# no display price for grouped product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I am displaying featured products on the home page. I can show everything related to product except pricing for grouped products. I do not know what wrong i am going here. I can display bundle product's minimum price but not price for grouped product.

I am using `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` to display price but seems to be not working for grouped products.

Comment: Usually `getPriceHtml()` works for grouped products. Have you tried reindexing the prices?

Comment: yes i did..but i have found a solution..

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution. I am looping through each product assosiated with grouped product

`

```
<?php 
     if ($_product->isGrouped()) 
            {
                $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
                $_taxHelper  = $this->helper('tax');
                $aProductIds = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());
                $minprice = 99999999999999;
                $_finalPrice = '';
                foreach ($aProductIds as $ids) 
                {
                        foreach ($ids as $id) 
                        {
                            $aProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
                            if ($minprice > $aProduct->getPriceModel()->getPrice($aProduct)) 
                            {
                                $minprice = $aProduct->getPriceModel()->getPrice($aProduct);
                                $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($aProduct, $aProduct->getFinalPrice());
                            }
                        }
                    echo $_coreHelper->currency($_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_finalPrice, $includingTax = true), true, false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
              echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);      
            }
            ?>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$groupedPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_grouped_price'); 
echo $groupedPrice->getMinPrice($_product->getId());
echo $groupedPrice->getMaxPrice($_product->getId());
```

On my site, I display the price range for grouped products. Of course if they are all the same price, I just display the min price